# Google closure compiler and teamcity / tfs

Tags: javascript, teamcity, google-closure-compiler

How to make teamcity and/or TFS 2010 to run closure compiler for js files in a project.
There are 2 reasons for using closure compiler:

1. error/warning detection
2. js minification/obfuscation - optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use rake builds and TeamCity. It calls closure to compile and minify all of our javascript as part of packaging for installers.

Its pretty simple in rake to do this, just use sh to do somethinj like:

```
sh "java -jar #{JS_TOOLS_DIR}/google-closure.jar --js=#{js_file} --js_output_file=#{min_file} " + "--warning_level QUIET --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY"
```

Comment: Seems like a valid answer to me, however, i found out a different way to do it: recent versions of closure-compiler contain built-in ant task. And teamcity can easily run ant tasks - main problem for me now is that it can run as a separate project only.

Comment: Bushed: With TeamCity 6.0 (almost out of EAP) you can have multiple build runners in a single build so you could chain through your ant task for the Closure part.